# Swift Xcode cant find MapKit as an outlet

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

after much researching i think i have found the problem of my coding.

I am trying to setup a app where users can see their locations after where they are.

I always get an error which says

> fatal error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value
>   (lldb)

And the error is showed as Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION at this line:

```
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
```

When i try to delete the line the exact same error shows up on another .mapView. So the error appears at everyline where i have used my mapkit and IBAOutlet(mapView).

I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. When i propertied the mapkit i went to the Main.Storyboard -> CTR + drag -> ViewController.swift and called it "mapView"

Thank you for your time

**Here is all of my codes**

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import CoreLocation
import MapKit  


class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.locationManager.delegate = self

    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

    }






    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    // MARK: - Location Delegate Methods

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
       let location = locations.last

        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1))

        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("Error:" + error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing outlet connection in storyboard and connecting it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a timing (or interface builder hookup) problem.

To avoid this, try changing the type of the outlet to `MKMapView?` and use optional coalesking like so:

```
self.mapView?.showsUserLocation = true
```

This at least takes care of the timing problem leading to a crash so you can pinpoint the problem more accurately.

If after the crash no map view is showing up, it might not be a timing but a interface builder hookup problem. Make sure you connected the map view to the outlet then.

Comment: Okei! This work! I am not sure if it will show my location yet! But it did show apples! But what does this mean? What is wrong?

Comment: Do you use by any chance a simulator?;)

Comment: Yes i do Sir! Again thank you so much. Can not believe that after a total of 2 days searching and trying to figure it out, a question mark was all i needed...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "weak" from the var MapView. If you hold no strong reference the outlet will be de-allocated immediately.